# CSS Kerning for Large Numbers

Tags: css, number-formatting, kerning, letter-spacing

I realise that in the states large numbers are formatted with a `,` between thousands so you would write `$1,000,000.00`. In South Africa a `,` is non-standard and could be used as a decimal point instead of the `.`.

We would write `$1000000.00` which is horrible to read. The typical solution is to use a bit of whitespace: `$1 000 000.00`.

The problem with that solution is that it still looks terrible.

If I assume values are currency formatted in a particular DOM element (i.e. the numbers are suffixed with `.00` even if it's double zero), the ideal solution would be to use CSS to somehow manipulate the kerning of every nth-last-letter. I have a strong preference not to use javascript but maybe that's not possible...

Is something like this possible? What's the best solution?

Comment: CSS has no capacity to target characters (except in the case of the `::first-letter` pseudo-element), so to do this you'd need to use JavaScript to wrap the groups of numbers with an element and then use `margin`/`padding` to supply the spacing.

Comment: Take a look at [this codepen](http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx) or [Lettering.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js) to control kerning of individual characters.

Comment: Thanks @quantumwannabe - both look good, you should put those as answers...

Answer (score 3):

I would think that using ordinary spaces and then reducing their width with CSS would do the trick.

e.g.

```
.currency {
    word-spacing: -2px
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/5f9c4cdu/

Comment: that's pretty clever! however, you'd need to add in those spaces yourself, or have something that automates that.

Comment: @ferr Nice of you to say so, thanks. I think the OP was saying that he could format the text with spaces or with commas, but I might be wrong.

Comment: If it's all static or he's fine with getting spaces in somehow, then it should work for him.

Comment: I think this is an awesome idea. I hadn't considered actually manipulating the size of the spaces. Obviously it's not the elegance of kerning the number but it's certainly a useful idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible- to manipulate the kerning of a font through css. Your best bet is to find a font with an ideal kerning built in and use that.

However, since you need variable kerning, I'd have to recommend using JS. It would be a simple script.

html:

```
<div class='currency comma-delimited'>1,000,000.00</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
var input = $('.currency.comma-delimited').text();
while(input.indexOf(',') != -1) {
    //replace each comma with a space
    input = input.replace(',',' ');
}
$('.currency.comma-delimited').text(input);
```

The following CSS-based solution is ridiculous and you shouldn't use it:

html:

```
<div class='currency'>
1<span class='space-delimited'></span>000</span class='space-delimited'></span>000.00
</div>
```

css:

```
.currency .space-delimited:after {
    content:' ';
    display:inline-block;
    height:1em;
    width:0.5em; /* control the size of the space, essentially the kerning */
}
```

Being realistic, you could combine the JS solution with this CSS solution to inject the .space-delimited span in place of the comma, thus giving you dynamic placement of the span and control of the kerning through the .space-delimited css.

Please view the snippet for a combined example.

```js
var input = $('.currency.comma-delimited').text();

while (input.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
  input = input.replace(',', '<span class="space-delimited"></span>');
}

$('.currency.comma-delimited').html(input);
```

```css
.currency .space-delimited:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 0.2em; /* this is your kerning variable! */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='currency comma-delimited'>
  1,000,000.00
</div>
```

Comment: That won't work because he wants kerning to be different for the same character in different contexts. A new font will make no difference.

Comment: ah I see, so "00" and "00 00". I'll add some tips to my post. thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to put spans around each thousand rather than having them arb around in the middle of text? I have rewarded the work you've put into the answer though ;)

Comment: The spans are replacing the comma and creating a space with width defined by css. If the span were around the thousands, it would still work, but the css would need to be set using :before instead of :after to define the space.